# Fast (Rspec) tests with and without Rails

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, stub, load-path

I have two classes:

1.Sale is a subclass of ActiveRecord; its job is to persist sales data to the database.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.total_for_duration(start_date, end_date)
    self.count(conditions: {date: start_date..end_date})
  end
  #...
end
```

2.SalesReport is a standard Ruby class; its job is to produce and graph information about Sales.

```
class SalesReport
  def initialize(start_date, end_date)
    @start_date = start_date
    @end_date = end_date
  end

  def sales_in_duration
    Sale.total_for_duration(@start_date, @end_date)
  end
  #...
end
```

Because I want to use TDD and I want my tests to run *really fast*, I have written a spec for SalesReport that doesn't doesn't load Rails:

```
require_relative "../../app/models/sales_report.rb"

class Sale; end
# NOTE I have had to re-define Sale because I don't want to
# require `sale.rb` because it would then require ActiveRecord.

describe SalesReport do
  describe "sales_in_duration" do
    it "calls Sale.total_for_duration" do
      Sale.should_receive(:total_for_duration)
      SalesReport.new.sales_in_duration
    end
  end
end
```

This test **works** when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/models/report_spec.rb`.

However this test fails when I run `bundle exec rake spec` with the error `superclass mismatch for class Sale (TypeError)`.  I know the error is happening because Tap is defined by `sale.rb` and inline within the spec.

**So my question is there a way to Stub (or Mock or Double) a class if that class isn't defined?**  This would allow me to remove the inline `class Sale; end`, which feels like a hack.

If not, how do I set up my tests such that they run correctly whether I run `bundle exec rspec` or `bundle exec rake spec`?

If not, is my approach to writing fast tests wrong?!

Finally, I don't want to use Spork.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSpec's recently added `stub_const` is specifically designed for cases like these:

```
describe SalesReport do
  before { stub_const("Sale", Class.new) }

  describe "sales_in_duration" do
    it "calls Sale.total_for_duration" do
      Sale.should_receive(:total_for_duration)
      SalesReport.new.sales_in_duration
    end
  end
end
```

You may also want to use [rspec-fire](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire) to use a test double in place of `Sale` that automatically checks all the mocked/stubbed methods exist on the real `Sale` class when running your tests with the real `Sale` class loaded (e.g. when you run your test suite):

```
require 'rspec/fire'

describe SalesReport do
  include RSpec::Fire

  describe "sales_in_duration" do
    it "calls Sale.total_for_duration" do
      fire_replaced_class_double("Sale")
      Sale.should_receive(:total_for_duration)
      SalesReport.new.sales_in_duration
    end
  end
end
```

If you rename `total_for_duration` on the real `Sale` class, rspec-fire will give you an error when you mock the method since it doesn't exist on the real class.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to check if "Sale" has already been defined

```
unless defined?(Sale)
  class Sale; end
end
```

Sale need not be a class either in your test so:

```
unless defined?(Sale)
  Sale = double('Sale')
end
```